# TestScript run time error NullPointerException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium, when I am working with Page object model in the execution time system displays java.lang.NullPointerException. Here I am going to provide the sample code:

```java
    TestUtil@class
    public class Testbase {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;

    public Testbase()
    {
        try
        {
        prop= new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:/TestMaven/DautAutomationTesting/src/main/java/com/qa/config/config.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void initialization()
    {
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("broswer");
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
    System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/ChromeSetup.exe");
    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {
    System.setProperty("WebDriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/geckodriver.exe");
    driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    
    }
    }
    
    LoginPage@class
        public class Loginpage extends Testbase{
        @FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='email']") WebElement Emailid;
        @FindBy(xpath="//img[@id='enterimg']") WebElement Enter;
        @FindBy(xpath="//img[@id='logo']") WebElement ATlogo;
        
        public Loginpage()
        {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
            }
        
        public String validatePageTitle()
        {
            return driver.getTitle();
        }
        
        public boolean validateATImage()
        {
            return ATlogo.isDisplayed();
        }
        
        
        public Regpage  Emailid(String eid)
        {
            Emailid.sendKeys(eid);
            Enter.submit();
            return new Regpage();
        }
        }
            
    LoginPageTest@class
    
    public class LoginpageTest extends Testbase{
    
        Loginpage loginpage;
        Regpage regpage;
        
        public LoginpageTest()
        {
            super();
        }
        
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp()
        {
            initialization();
            loginpage = new Loginpage();
        }
        
        @Test(priority=1)
        public void loginPageTitleTest()
        {
            String title=loginpage.validatePageTitle();
            Assert.assertEquals(title, "Index");
        }
        
        @Test(priority=2)
        public void  validateATimageTest()
        {
            boolean flag=loginpage.validateATImage();
            Assert.assertTrue(flag);
        }
        }
```

**ErrorMessage**

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException  at
com.qa.testbase.Testbase.initialization(Testbase.java:44)   at
com.qa.test.LoginpageTest.setUp(LoginpageTest.java:24)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)   at
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)  at
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)    at
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)  at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)     at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)     at
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)   at
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)    at
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)     at
org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: it seems like you have a typo while trying get which browser your are dealing with via prop.getProperty("broswer"). it should "browser", not "broswer". This causes your driver to not get initialized, which then causes the NullPointerException to occur when trying to the call driver.manage().window().maximize().

Answer (score 0):

I can see **two possible issues** here. You need to take the time to debug line by line to leave the only relevant one:

1. When you call `initialization();` the first line is `String browserName = prop.getProperty("broswer");`. However `TestBase` constructor is never called explicitly (I am not sure if TestNg does this). This means that your `prop` object is likely `null` which causes your code to fail on this line.
2. If TestNg runs the constructor implicitly using reflection (however this is likely not true) then when you run the line `String browserName = prop.getProperty("broswer");` you might be missing property `browser` in your property file. This means that `getProperty()` method return `null` since you do not provide any default value. This eventually causes your code to fail on the line `if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))`